# Multiplication properties in rings of matrices

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be an arbitrary ring and let $M_n(R)~~(n>1)~$ be the ring of all $n ~ х ~ n$ matrices with elements from $R$ with usual matrix addition and multiplication.

1) Is it right that there are zero divisors in $M_n(R)$ iff $R$ is non-trivial?

2) Which necessary and sufficient conditions on $R$ do we need for $M_n(R)$ to be non-commutative?

3) Suppose $R$ has no unity. Is it right that this condition is sufficient for each element of $M_n(R)$ to be a zero divisor? If not, how can we construct an example of matrix that isn't zero divisor?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT

By zero-divisors i mean NON-ZERO elements.

Comment: What do you mean by a trivial ring? About your third question note that if $R$ has no zero-divisors, the scalar matrices are not zero-divisors either.

Comment: @AndreaMori $n>1$. Maybe that was added in an edit?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I didn't make any edits. This condition was in the question from the beginning.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: if $r$ is not a zero-divisor in $R$, the scalar matrix $diag(r,...,r)$ is not a zero-divisor in $M_n(R)$, whatever $n$ !

Comment: @AndreaMori
By trivial ring i mean the ring which has just one element (i.e. zero element).

Comment: @Igor: Ok. If $R$ has an element $r\neq0$ the matrix which has $r$ in place $(1,n)$ and $0$ everywhere else has square $0$ as soon as $n\geq2$.

Comment: @AndreaMori Am i right that $M_n(R)$ has a matrix that is not a zero divisor iff $\exists x,y\in R ~~ xy\neq 0$?

Comment: @AndreaMori The question wasn't whether all elements were zero divisors, but whether there were any zero divisors.

Comment: Let $R=2{\bf Z}/8{\bf Z}$. Then $(6)(6)\ne0$, but I'm not sure there's a matrix that isn't a zero-divisor.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I know what ${\bf Z}/8{\bf Z}$ is but i don't know what $2{\bf Z}/8{\bf Z}$ means. Could you explain please what it is or at least how this ring is called?

Comment: $2{\bf Z}$ is the ring of all multiples of $2$. $8{\bf Z}$ is the subring, containing all the multiples of $8$. $2{\bf Z}/8{\bf Z}$ is the quotient ring. You can think of its elements as being $\{{0,2,4,6\}}$, with operations performed modulo $8$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the meaning of (1) is that there are *non-trivial* zero divisors...etc.? But

$$\begin{pmatrix}0&0&\ldots&0&r\\0&0&&\ldots&0\\\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots\\0&0&0&\ldots&0\end{pmatrix}$$

is a nilpotent matrix, and thus it is a zero divisor (which is non zero if $\,0\ne r\in R\,$)

Also

$$\begin{pmatrix}0&r\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}s&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\neq \begin{pmatrix}s&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0&r\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

whenever $\;sr\neq 0\;$ , so assuming the ring $\,R\,$ is non trivial **and** with non-trivial multiplication (like the one we can define on any abelian group and defining every product to be zero), if $\,n>1\,$ the product won't be commutative.

The last part: $\,2\Bbb Z\,$ is a non-unitary ring...